# spring-data: foreign-key as a primary

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with 100 fields, which i want to split into 3-4 tables. While creating, the primary key for one of the table would become foreign and primary key for remaining tables.

I tried something like this

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(Entity1.class)
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id",  referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Entity1 id;
    
    ...
}


@Repository
public interface Entity1Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity1, String> {
    Optional<Entity1> findById(String id);
}

@Repository
public interface Entity2Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity2, Entity1> {
    Optional<Entity2> findById(Entity1 id);
}
```

It is creating the tables, but giving error as **This class [class xyz.Entity2] does not define an IdClass**

Also looked at few of the references, like use of @MapsId. But non of the solution was working for me. Any inputs?

Thanks

Venkata Madhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what approach you were trying with the `MapsId` feature. But it certainly can help you in this situation. Here is your example code with `MapsId` implementation:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entity1")
    private Entity2 entity2;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entity1")
    private Entity3 entity3;
}
```

This is the parent class that will only hold the reference of the `OneToOne` association. The child will be the owner of the relation.

Here is your Entity2 child:

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String value;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

As you said you will be splicing your main entity into multiple child I went ahead and used another child entity to clarify my point:

```
@Entity
public class Entity3 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String value;

   @MapsId
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

You may have noticed by now that I am using:

1. `@JoinColumn` annotation in the child classes to tell hibernate that use the id column of the child to map this `OneToOne` relation with `Entity1` class.
2. I am using cascadeType = PERSIST in the child classes.

The first step is required to perform the relation mapping with id. And the second step is required to save all 3 entities into the database in the same transaction. More on this later.

> Let's see how you can now save all of these entities into the database.

```
@Transactional
public void saveEntities() {
    Long id = 1L;
    Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
    entity1.setId(id);
    entity1.setName("Test1Entity1: " + id);

    Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
    entity2.setValue("entity2Value: " + id);
    entity2.setEntity1(entity1);
    entity2Repository.save(entity2);
    Entity3 entity3 = new Entity3();
    entity3.setValue("Test3Entity:" + id);
    entity3.setEntity1(entity1);
    entity3Repository.save(entity3);
}
```

Notice that I didn't save the `Entity1` class with the repository. It is being saved by the `cascadeType=PERSIST` param that I passed into the `OneToOne` annotation operation.

> This should be able to save all the entities along with the parent one.

**Note:** Earlier I was saying about cascadeType=PERSIST and why it was important here. If you don't use that then you had to call the `Entity1` repository method explicitly to save its object to the database first then you could set them into the child entities. But if you do so, hibernate will throw: `a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session` exception while you perform save operation on child entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entity1")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Entity2 entity2;
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "entity1_id")
    private String id;
    
    ...

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id)
    private Entity1 entity1;
}

public interface Entity2Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity2, String>
```

Test:

```
@Test
void save() {
    Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
    entity1.setId("iddddd");

    Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
    detail.setEntity1(entity1);

    this.entity2Repository.save(entity2);
}
```

**Reference**: [Shared Primary Key](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one#spk-model)

Comment: This works with small correction instead of @Column(name = "entity1_id)  it should be @ **Join** Column(name = "entity1_id)

Comment: Ah yes, edited!